# How do we model the behaviour of circuits on ultrashort time scales (< ns)?

Tags: integrated-circuit, electromagnetism, kirchhoffs-laws, physics, transient

The electric field has a finite propagation speed. How do we describe the behaviour of circuits on timescales before even changes in the electric field have reached the entire circuit?

Is this is a phenomenon that integrated circuit designers are concerned with? How do charge carriers flow in a wire on these time scales?

For example, imagine that we just connected a battery to the circuit below. Assuming that each LED is physically identically, would they all emit light at **exactly** the same time, not even an attosecond apart? Assume that we measure an arbitrary number of samples to average out any quantum mechanical timing randomness.
[image]

I am aware of [parasitic elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitic_element_%28electrical_networks%29) and I know that these is a deep connection between [relativity and electromagnetism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_electromagnetism). I am curious to know how these effects can be mathematically modelled and simulated.

Comment: To model circuit behavior on the timescale you are talking about, you have to use transmission line concepts. Assuming the wire is somewhat uniform, there would be some characteristic impedance to it. The current that flows initially, due to a step in the output voltage, would be determined by the transmission line impedance. In other words, before the first reflection comes back, the current follows V=IZ, where Z is the characteristic impedance of the transmission line. You are right that the electric field propagates at a finite speed (usually slower than the free-space speed of C).

Answer (score 3):

The guy you seek advice from is Maxwell, not Kirchhoff.

If you want to use circuit theory and its variables like voltage and current (and Kirchhoff's Laws are about voltages and currents), the overall dimension of your circuit d must be way smaller than the signal's wavelength, which is clearly not given if your thought experiment is about the LEDs flashing along the wire, one after each other. In that case, one would have to use field theory (with electric and magnetic fields). You still can integrate over all relevant elements within a given sphere and find out that sums become zero, but that's Maxwell, not Kirchhoff.

Here's an excerpt from Chua, L. O., C. A. Desoer, E. S. Kuh: Linear and Nonlinear Circuits. McGraw-Hill Book Company, New York 1987, ISBN 0-07-010898-6, p1-3; online (in part) at http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee100/fa08/lectures/EE100supplementary_notes_2.pdf.

[image]

The fact that this is on the first three pages of a > 800 pages book about circuit theory, put almost as a disclaimer in the first chapter, called "Kirchhoff's Laws", kind of speaks of itself.

Comment: But do all of the LEDs turn on at the same time?

Comment: @ScottLawson 1s*10e-18: No. In your example, the shortest time of interest is so short that we can't assume the circuit to be lumped, and electromagnetic waves will not propagate virtually instantaneously. Kirchhoff's Laws will not hold. At the time scale you're talking about, you need field theory and you need to consider your wires as transmission lines along which the waves will propagate some factor slower than the speed of light. It really depends on how you define "same time", and your definition ("attosecond apart") puts us in the domain where we can't use lumped circuit approximations.

Answer (score 0):

Wires do have inductance. Thus, the LEDs you connect should turn on with an order. However, it is almost impossible to see that.

Comment: All of those inductors are in series. They do not (until you also consider parasitic capacitance) cause the LEDs to light in sequence.

Comment: @ThePhoton Agree, but the question talks about attoseconds, and this makes us consider inductance and capacitance (i.e. transmission line theory). So you either neglect parasitics (i.e. you do not think of the wires as transmission lines) by assuming the shortest time interval of interest satisfies d << c*delta(t), or you use field theory (Maxwell, not Kirchhoff), consider inductance and capacitance, and care about attoseconds. It's "either/or"; Kirchhoff "together with" attoseconds won't work. Attoseconds without parasitic capacitance (transm. line) won't work, eitehr.